# Chrome Browser not accepting user credentials in URL with @

Tags: google-chrome, browser

I'm trying to log users into another application by passing the user credentials through the URL. The way it has always been setup has been done like so,

http://username:password@status.domain.com:8080

However, chrome doesn't like this. To fix it in IE, we needed to add a passfix to the users browser.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you using Chrome 19? It looks like it might be a bug. https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=128902

Comment: Having the username visible in the URL bar is apparently a security issue (due to the potential for phishing), but that shouldn't preclude using it for login.

Comment: Yeah I'm using chrome 19, thanks for spotting that. I'm aware it's a security issue, but as you stated, it shouldn't effect login since it could potentially be done within a forum too.